# How do I close out of tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Don't worry about the variable, I'm just wondering why I can't close out of tkinter to make a new one.

```
def trainup():
    global newbw
    global mg
    global pmg
    mg=mg+1
    newbw.destroy()
    pmg=str(mg)
    print("you have leveled up your money gain your new money gain will be:" + pmg)
    train()

def train():
    import tkinter
    print("welcome to the training area")
    print("click the button to train")
    newbw=tkinter.Tk()
    b=tkinter.Button(newbw, text="train", command=trainup)
    b.pack()
    newbw.mainloop()
```

Comment: `newbw` is defined in `train()` and `trainup()` cannot see `newbw` because of this. You will need `global newbw` in `train()` for this code to work. That said there are a few issues with this setup you should change.

Comment: thank you it worked like a charm now all i have to fiqure out is postioning

Comment: Also, it's generally considered best practice to avoid using global variables like this. It's better to pass them as parameters to functions. Doing so helps avoid problems like this. As you write more code, these types of issues will come up a lot more often and in more complex ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code that you should address.

1. `import tkinter` should not be in a function. All imports should be at the top of your code. As it stands now you are importing tkinter every time the `train()` function is called.
2. To you main question as to why you cannot destroy the root windows. Your `newbw` tk instance is defined locally in `train()` thus nothing outside of that function can see this variable. You will at the very least have to add `global newbw` to the `train()` function. Though the best course of action is to move the root window into the global namespace anyway or write it as a class.
3. `mg` does not exist in your code so this will cause errors in this example.
4. You really should not be deleting the root window and recreating it. Instead you should manage a frame within the root window or a 2nd top level window.

Minimum change needed to make this code work:

```
import tkinter


def trainup():
    global newbw, mg, pmg
    # mg=mg+1
    newbw.destroy()
    # pmg = str(mg)
    print("you have leveled up your money gain your new money gain will be:")  # + pmg)
    train()


def train():
    global newbw
    print("welcome to the training area")
    print("click the button to train")
    newbw = tkinter.Tk()
    b = tkinter.Button(newbw, text="train", command=trainup)
    b.pack()
    newbw.mainloop()

train()
```

A better solution would probably be to update a label instead of trying to recreate a window every time.

Something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


def trainup():
    global mg, pmg
    mg += 1
    pmg = str(mg)
    status_label.config(text="you have leveled up your money gain your new money gain will be:" + pmg)


newbw = tk.Tk()
mg = 0
pmg = 0
tk.Label(newbw, text="welcome to the training area\nclick the button to train").pack()
status_label = tk.Label(newbw, text='')
status_label.pack()
tk.Button(newbw, text="train", command=trainup).pack()
newbw.mainloop()
```

Here is an example where we update a frame containing a widget. Its not really a better option here but the example should be useful down the road.

```
import tkinter as tk


def trainup():
    global mg, pmg
    mg += 1
    pmg = str(mg)
    status_label.config(text="you have leveled up your money gain your new money gain will be:" + pmg)


def update_frame():
    global frame, status_label
    if frame is not None:
        frame.destroy()
    frame = tk.Frame(newbw)
    frame.pack()
    status_label = tk.Label(frame, text='')
    status_label.pack()


newbw = tk.Tk()
mg = 0
pmg = 0
frame = None
update_frame()

tk.Label(newbw, text="welcome to the training area\nclick the button to train").pack()
tk.Button(newbw, text="train", command=trainup).pack()
newbw.mainloop()
```

Comment: im just suprised how fast you wrote this makes me feel kinda stupid because im only just now learning about tkinter so thank you

Comment: @arandomdosfile don't feel stupid. I have spent the better part of the last 2 years learning and using tkinter professionally at my place of work. I just happen to have the time invested to make quick judgments and corrections on a simple interface. If you stick with it you can get to that point as well.

Comment: You really should not be deleting the root window and recreating it. Instead you should manage a frame within the root window or a 2nd top level window.

Comment: for that i dont understand what you mean

Comment: i see so you takeing somthing like b=tk.button(newbw, text =5) and spimply changing it inside the code  b=tk.button(newbw, text =4)

Comment: @arandomdosfile yes. You can simply update the labels in a widget instead of destroying them. There are times where destroying a container (window, frame, toplevel, etc) can be useful but most of the time you will want to simply update your widgets.

Comment: This was very useful I love that I am able come here to talk with real professinals on a different website sombody gave me some code but the thing was it had a backdoor in it and my files were wiped this is so much better thank you so much

Comment: @arandomdosfile A backdoor... That is not something I have ever encountered on SO. Not even sure how that may happen. That is unfortunate. All people who post on here are volunteering their time. They can be professionals or hobbyist I just happen to be both :D. I am still far from being an expert though so I would say always take the advice you get here with a grain of salt and keep an open mind for other opinions out there.

Comment: i have another problem with removing tkinter i dont know why its wont remove the pack '

Comment: i want to remove the button within the fram

Comment: but also it has to be inside a def function

Comment: Well that sounds like a different question to me. Make a new post about your new problem.